# How to properly store $ dollar values from a given excel spreadsheet into a postgresql database

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, csv

I'm trying to store dollar values in a `postgresql` database. I want to later be able to filter and manipulate the data.

I'm given monthly excel spreadsheet reports and my goal is to store all that data for later use. I've downloaded the csv. However, one field is dollar amounts with a `$` symbol. I believe storing as money data type is not recommended and I want to store as a numeric data type. How would I go about removing the `$` from the csv? would it be better to store as text? remove `$` from file before anything? Just don't know which way to go with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some options.

In Excel, you could change the formatting from money to number, but that could introduce rounding issues.

You could import the CSV as-is into a staging table, with the field as a string. Then, strip off the $ symbol and convert to decimal.

Depending on what you are using to import the file, most ETL tools will allow you to transform that field on the fly and strip the $ symbol and convert to decimal.

Again, you've got options. The best one depends on your environment and business rules.